# How to handle 'undo' and 'redo' functions in content-editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm working on a `contenteditable` div and trying to create a text editor, but in this text editor I'm adding some elements like `image` and `div`. If I'm supposed to add and remove elements in editable div and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> undo function is not working (not getting element back).

Please let me know is there any solution for this. Undo function is only working for text inside the `contenteditable` div. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to create your own undo/redo handle for that. You can have an object that will keep the state (lets say that you save X back/forward steps) and when you hit the ctrl+z (catch that is pretty simple) you can just update the content of your div to the previous content.

Comment: Thank you, but how to write our own undo/redo function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.execCommand` for undo and redo the changes in the editable div's. You can refer this document for more details [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

Comment: document.execCommand() is deprecated according to developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand